# React Material UI Autocomplete highlight searched text in results

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, node-modules

I am using the Autocomplete component from the Material UI (v0.20.0) component library in ReactJS project. I have tried finding an implementation for this functionality but haven't come across a good example. I want to be able to highlight/format the text that the user enters in the search results similar to the attached image.
[image: Search Guidelines Image based on Material UI]

Comment: What version of material-ui are you using? v0 or v1?

Comment: I am using v0.20.0

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Material-ui v0.xx then please take a look at below example.

To apply styles to user entered text you have to use inputStyle prop as like below.

Also I have mentioned the other styles for floating label, underline, hint text etc which may help community.

```
 const styles = {
    floatingSearchLabelStyle: {
      color: '#fff',
      fontFamily: 'Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande'
    },
    inputSearchStyleText: {
      color: '#fff'
    },
    underlineSearchStyle : {
      borderColor: '#fff'
    },
    hintSearchStyle: {
      color: '#fff'      
    }
}
<AutoComplete
      floatingLabelText="Search people"
      hintText="Search with name"
      dataSource = {dataSource}
      style={{marginTop: '-20px'}}
      maxSearchResults={10}
      anchorOrigin={{vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'left'}}
      animated={true}
      onNewRequest= {this.handleNewRequest}
      onUpdateInput={this.handleUpdateInput}
      filter={AutoComplete.fuzzyFilter}        
      inputStyle={styles.inputSearchStyleText} 
      underlineStyle={styles.underlineSearchStyle} 
      underlineFocusStyle={styles.underlineSearchStyle} 
      hintStyle={styles.hintSearchStyle} 
      floatingLabelStyle={styles.floatingSearchLabelStyle}
    />
```

Hope this answer helps you if you are using material-ui v0.xx.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I am looking for. The inputStyle property only changes the style of the text that is typed in the text area. I have updated the image in the original post to make it more clear as to what I want. Also I am using v0.20.0.

Comment: hoo ok got it. Let me try

Answer (score 1):

In Material-UI Version 5+ we can use renderOption property to highlight the options based on input entered by user in the following way

```
<Autocomplete
    renderOption={React.useCallback((props, option, { inputValue }) => {
      function boldString(str, substr) {
          const strRegExp = new RegExp(substr, 'g')
          return str.replace(strRegExp, '<b style=color:#1e99fa !important;>' + substr + '</b>')
      }
      return (
          <Box component='li' {...props}>
              <div style={{width: '50%'}} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: boldString(option.label, inputValue) }}/>
          </Box>
      )
  })}
/>
```